# Calculating Sprague–Grundy numbers for impartial game with a loop

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Suppose we have a two-player game with states $\{A,B,C,D\}$ and allowable moves:
$$A \to B, B \to A$$
$$ A \to C, B \to C$$
$$ C \to D$$
Since there are no moves starting from $D$, if a player is in state $D$ the player loses. This seems to satisfy the [definition for impartial game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impartial_game), so by applying [Sprage Grundy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem) naively we would expect each state of the game to be equivalent to a nimber.

However, suppose we start in state $A$ of the game. The first player cannot go to state $C$, as this would cause the second player to play $C \to D$, ending the game. So the first player plays $A \to B$. Similarly, the second player must play $B \to A$. So the game never ends.

How are Nimbers assigned in this particular case? I have also read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/combinatorial-game-theory-set-3-grundy-numbersnimbers-and-mex/) that for a game where the states and transitions form a poset we can define the nimbers inductively using 'mex', but this isn't applicable here because $A \to B$ and $B \to A$ means the game isn't a poset?

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem: "For the purposes of the Sprague–Grundy theorem, a game is a two-player sequential game of perfect information satisfying the ending condition (all games come to an end: there are no infinite lines of play)"

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated ah I missed that - thanks. Does this mean though that Sprague-Grundy only applies to poset games? Is it supposed to be surprising that we can find equivalent nim games for poset games?

Comment: I don't think it _only_ applies to poset games, but it only applies to games that end (poset games are just a subset of games that end).

Comment: @JoshuaLin Take care when speaking of "poset games". The phrase "poset game" has [a strict definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poset_game) that's much more narrow than "a game whose graph of positions and allowable moves (in the style of your example) is the graph of a poset".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the [Sprague-Grundy Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem) only applies to "non-loopy" impartial games that do not admit infinite runs. However, there is a generalization which can handle loopy games, discovered by Cedric Smith and independently by Aviezri Fraenkel. It is covered in detail in section IV.4 of the textbook [Combinatorial Game Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-146/) by Aaron N. Siegel.

I have a more elaborate summary in [a Mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/149084/28209), but basically, you *try* to build up finite "nimbers", temporarily assigning $\infty$ to anything you don't know yet. You can replace an $\infty$ with a [mex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_%28mathematics%29) $m$ when all of the options of value higher than $m$ (including $\infty$) can move to $m$. When you can't get rid of any more $\infty$s, the process stops and you just note which finite nimbers each $\infty$ can move to (so you can decide who wins in a sum).

In the game posted in the question, $D$ gets nimber $0$ because there are no options. $C$ gets nimber $1$ because its only option is $D=0$. Can $A$ and $B$ be changed from $\infty$? Well, $A$ would have to get the nimber $\mathrm{mex}\{1,\infty\}=0$, but $B$ doesn't have an option of $0$, so $A$ stays as an $\infty$. And similarly for $B$ by symmetry. Therefore, $A$ and $B$ don't get a finite value, but could be denoted as $\infty\{1\}$ for "an $\infty$ whose only finite nimber option is $1$".

Since $A$ is an $\infty$ and can't move to $0$ (which would be a winning move), it's a "drawn" position, rather than a win for either player. And since $A$ is $\infty\{1\}$, if we add $A$ to something with nimber $1$ (like $C$) then we get a game where the first player can win: simply move from $A$ to $C$, leaving the opponent with a sum of two nimber-$1$ games, which is a losing position by the usual Sprague-Grundy theory.

For a different example where there are no $\infty$s in the end, despite a loop, see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1747268/26369) to [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1738896/26369).